# Как реализовать отправку файла?

Tags: php, файлы

Здравствуйте! Делаю дамп базы и хочу его выдавать сразу на скачку файла. На сервере файл сохраняется отлично, все как надо. Но на скачку получаю файл который начинается с хтмл кода страницы с которой делаю закачку, а после этого кода уже дамп. Помогите разобраться откуда этот код берется. Вот код выдачи файла:

```
if ($stream)
{
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$dump_name.$ofdot);
    if($gzip) header('Content-type: application/x-gzip'); else header('Content-type: text/plain');
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0,pre-check=0");
    header("Pragma: public");
    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: Оформите код как полагается и приведите больше примеров. Из вопроса ясно, что проблема не в этом куске кода...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас скорее всего html идет в начале php-файла, потом стоИт код отдачи вашего дампа. Поставьте код PHP в начало файла и, обязательно, после отдачи дампа прерывайте выполнение скипта - `exit();`

Comment: мда, сам почему то не додумался про код вначале :) спасибо, все на своих местах!